# print number of employee working directly or indirectly under each manager(oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a Employee table like

```
managername varchar2(20),
salary number(10,2),
empname varchar2(20),
Constraint [PK_Emp] Primary key (empname),
Constraint [FK_Emp] Foreign key (managername) references employee (empname) on delete cascade

mangername         salary        empname
------         ------         --------------
""              1000              Sumanta
Sumanta         1000              Arpita
Sumanta         1000              Pradip
Arpita          1000              Sujon
Sujon           1000              Arpan
Sujon           1000              Jayanti
```

I want to get count of all the employees that directly or indirectly work under each manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive CTE:

```
with cte(managername, empname, level) as (
      select managername, empname, 0
      from employee
      union all
      select e.managername, cte.empname, level + 1
      from cte join
           employee e
           on cte.managername = e.empname
    )
select managername, count(*)
from cte
group by managername;
```

This should work in 11g Release 2.  It seems to have trouble in [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/105e7/5) although basically the same code works in [SQL Server](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d5042/2).

Comment: i dont know why this isnt working. its giving error at first line near  level column which should hve worked.

Comment: @user3211808 . . . I don't know either.  The syntax seems right for a recursive CTE, and right now I only have SQL Fiddle to test on.